# How I can register ipython in Mac OS with latest versions of python?

Tags: python, ipython

I have installed ipython through easy_install but it didn't create the file in /usr/local/bin/ as usual.

I know if I use older version of easy_install of python, for example 2.6 I have this file under /usr/local/bin:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'ipython==0.13','console_scripts','ipython'
__requires__ = 'ipython==0.13'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('ipython==0.13', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
)
```

How I can get running ipython with latest version of python in /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: Are you using the official Apple-provided Python, or have you installed a different version that you're using?

Comment: I suppose yes, cause the path is : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources